# Using Python to scrape ReferenceUSA

Tags: python, web-scraping

first I am very new to Python so excuse the dumb questions.

I am using Robobrowser and start the browser using the code below. Note that I have to log into the site for first I log in and then navigate to the search results page (which I have hard coded):

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser 
from datetime import datetime
import re 
import csv

browser = RoboBrowser(history = True, parser = 'html.parser', user_agent='chrome')
browser.open('https://cas.columbia.edu/cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fwww1.columbia.edu%2fsec-cgi-bin%2fcul%2fprox%2fezpwebserv-ezproxy.cgi%3furl%3dezp.2aHR0cDovL3d3dy5yZWZlcmVuY2V1c2EuY29t')

form = browser.get_form(class_='fm-v clearfix' )
form['username'].value = '**************'
form['password'].value = '**************'
browser.submit_form(form)

url = 'http://www.referenceusa.com.ezproxy.cul.columbia.edu/UsBusiness/Result/41526a3b232941b0ae8df36a9870fec6'
browser.open(url)
```

What I am trying to do is build a scraper to get data off of ReferenceUSA. I have the website open and looking at HTML I see the element I want coded as:

```
<a href="#" class="action-view-record" data-all-url="/UsBusiness/Detail/All/41526a3b232941b0ae8df36a9870fec6/0?recordId=366190858" data-tagged-url="/UsBusiness/Detail/Tagged/41526a3b232941b0ae8df36a9870fec6?recordId=366190858">034 Efi</a>
```

from here I want to get the text so I tried:

```
companies = browser.find_all(class_='action-view-record')
for company in companies:
    company_name = company.text
    print(company_name)
```

The problem is that when I run the code nothing is printed. I think the page opens up properly because I tried:

```
links = browser.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

and that lists all the navigation links at the top/bottom of the page (e.g. about us, contact, etc.). But none of the links from the actual search result.

I would also like to get the links from this  tag so i can follow the page into the details. Here I have the additional problem that the HREF = '#'. So how can I get the link?

thanks!

Comment: What is your `browser` here?  If you could provide the code where you instantiate the browser (whatever it is) and point it at the website, I think that would be useful.  Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason it's `class_` and not just `class`?

Comment: @SuperStew `class` is a reserved word in Python, so it can't be a named argument. Assuming OP is using beautifulsoup, "Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument class_:"

Comment: @Kevin fair enough

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I added the browser instantiation code. I think that part is working because I was able to pull out text from the pages after logging in as well as from the search results URL.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not really sure how to explain this but the class value is an attribute of tag "a". There are two main ways to solve this,

1)

```
companies = browser.find_all(a)

for company in companies:
    if company.has_attr("class") and company.attrs['class'] == "action-view-record":
        print(company.text)
```

2)

The other way which is a little cleaner works by actually specifying the attrs in the find_all function. This can be done as follows:

```
companies = browser.find_all("a", {"class": "action-view-record"})
for company in companies:
    print(company.text)
```

And of course, because python is the bees knees you could actually accomplish all of this inside a list comprehension as such:

```
companies = [company.text for company in browser.find_all("a", {"class": "action-view-record"})]
```

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

I have never used robobrowser before but from the [github page](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) it seems you can find :

```
<div class="teaser-icon">
   <span class="mega-octicon octicon-checklist"></span>
</div>
```

using -

```
 browser.find('div.teaser-icon')
```

so... this might work for you,

```
 browser.find('a.action-view-record')
```

also make sure that you are in the right point in the html tree if the element is in side of another like -

```
<head>
   <body>
     <a class="action-view-record"> TEXT </a>
   </body>
</head>
```

you may need to do the find("a") from body like this.

```
head = browser.find('head')
body = head.find("body")
atags = body.find_all("a")
```

Comment: It didn't :( I used the 1) ad 2) option. but nothing printed. I added a dummy print('test') line within the loop and it seems python cannot find any <A> tags with that class. I double checked and the text I am looking for is indeed wrapped in <A class = "action-view-record">